# Mockito response is null after adding ZonedDateTime module by registerModule

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

Mockito response is null after adding ZonedDateTime module by registerModule..
This is the test I am writing...

```
@PostMapping("/bankStatement")
fun getBankStatementList(@Valid @RequestBody request: GenericRequest<BankStatementRequestDTO>): ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> {
    return createSuccessResponse(bankStatementService.getBankStatementList(request.data))
}
```

```
fun getBankStatementListSuccess() {
    val DEFAULT_DATE:ZonedDateTime  = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(0L), ZoneOffset.UTC);
    val request = GenericRequest(
        BankStatementRequestDTO(
            10,
            1,
            "",
            emptyList(),
            DEFAULT_DATE,
            DEFAULT_DATE,
            "03b3238c-66bb-4a4a-b205-4a9e8231b420"
        )
    )
    val response =
        BankStatementListResponseDTO(
            listOf(
                BankStatementResponseDTO(
                    "XXX123",
                    "CREDIT",
                    "upi-123213",
                    "03b3238c-66bb-4a4a-b205-4a9e8231b420",
                    "UPI",
                    BigDecimal(1234),
                    "remarks",
                    DEFAULT_DATE,
                    DEFAULT_DATE,
                    "CLAIMED",
                    "COIN12345678900"
                )
            ),
            1
        )

    Mockito.`when`(bankStatementService.getBankStatementList(request.data)).thenReturn(response)
    val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    objectMapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
    mvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post("/api/v1/bankStatement")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request))
    ).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
}
```

The Error

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.coinomerelaunch.brokeradminbackend.shared.dto.ResponseAdapterKt.createSuccessResponse, parameter dto
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.coinomerelaunch.brokeradminbackend.shared.dto.ResponseAdapterKt.createSuccessResponse, parameter dto
    at app//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
```

When I am using Date instead of ZonedDateTime test works..
after adding ZonedDate ..I have to add library

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.5")
```

also added these lines

```
val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    objectMapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
```

```
content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request))
```

but not works

Someone please help me why the mockito response is not getting mocked when I add the jackson library ..or Im missing something

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash still the same issue presists
Parameter specified as non-null is null, mean the mockito response is null

Comment: Have you tried adding the Kotlin module to the objectMapper: `objectMapper.registerKotlinModule()`?

Comment: yes but that is also giving same response.